# Какие методы класса String нужно специфицировать как noexcept?

Tags: c++, строки, noexcept

Решаю курс на степике, там вот такой тест.Перепробовал уже все варианты, никак не могу понять в чем ошибка.

Выберите все подходящие ответы из списка:

Конструктор по-умолчанию.

Конструктор копирования.

Перемещающий конструктор.

Оператор присваивания.

Перемещающий оператор присваивания.

Деструктор.

Метод size().

Метод clear().

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: *"Перепробовал уже все варианты"* - приводите свои попытки с пояснением, почему так. А вообще тест бестолковый, так как никакого "нужно" тут нет. Лучше не терять время на степике.

Comment: @user7860670 согласно документации выбираю два последних метода, а также перемещающий конструктор и перемещающий оператор присваивания

Comment: Решилось - верные ответы: всё, кроме конструктора копирования и оператора присваивания

Comment: ¿Согласно какой документации? В стандарте языка такого класса нет. А если реализовывать самостоятельно, то необходимость наличия `noexcept` зависит от реализации. *"верные ответы: всё, кроме конструктора копирования и оператора присваивания"* - это не верные ответы

Comment: Ну так если подумать, все логично. Конструктор по умолчанию ничего не аллоцирует, значит кидать там нечему. Перемещающие special members кидать не могут. size должен просто вернуть число, там тоже кидать нечему. Деструктор помечен как noexcept имплиситно, руками его помечать не надо. Только на счет clear я что-то с налету не уверен. А вообще вопрос стремный конечно.